# Get Error 'The HTTP version specified is not supported.' when using nginx proxy pass a signed url to download a file in AWS S3

Tags: amazon-web-services, http, nginx, amazon-s3

I have a s3 private object, get an signed URL by code, I have a try and it work fine, then i make a server nginx proxy like this:

```
http://my.domain/object?signedtoken...
```

pass to:

```
https://s3.ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/mybucket/object?signedtoken...
```

But I get the error:

```
<Error>
<Code>HttpVersionNotSupported</Code>
<Message>The HTTP version specified is not supported.</Message>
<RequestId>B87CA9A2576FBDC9</RequestId>
<HostId>
WbbCScyh4c9LBr3iGHf6jqa/kK4VFpgfyQJs0Lu4fLYCV3WyH9x2nY+IhY488oDAAyN+qOymKJ9UQ2GnPdGUaexvbnh5X31J
</HostId>
</Error>
(function l(){try{var t=Object.keys(CoinHive).length;t&&e.postMessage({cmd:"block_miner"},e.top.location.protocol+"//"+e.top.location.hostname)}catch(n){var o=document.getElementById("x-test-ch");null!==o&&o.remove()}})();
```

I don't know what wrong  with this, I't just a simple proxy_pass on nginx, the nginx proxy pass the signed url work fine with the minio server, but It still get error with S3 storage.

Comment: What's going on in that last line of the error?  That's not S3.  It looks like either your server or your browser has been compromised by some malware.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot I think my server or browser not compromised by any malware, I'm try to build the nginx proxy by docker, it still get this error, although I'm still want to make this under proxy to hold on my domain name, but I'm using redirect for now, get the s3 domain but it working

Comment: I believe CoinHive is a virus/trojan. You need to find and eliminate this, wherever it is. Example:
 https://malwaretips.com/blogs/remove-coinhive-miner-virus/

Comment: Thank you so much, I focus above blog. Hopping this will be resolve.